# add icon to wpform submit button

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

hi i want to make the form button same like in the image.
the link of the form is this
http://ministerievanlicht.com/contact/

the code is this that will get the button same to same but it not worked.

```css
.button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  background: #333333;
  color: white;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events:none;
  max-width:660px;
  border-bottom:solid gray 1px
    font-family: DIN pro;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button .fa {
  padding:1em;
  pointer-events:auto;
  width:1.5em;
}
.button::before {
  content: '';
  padding: 1em
}
```

and here is the custom css is this
i want to add icon at the end of the button

```css
div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=date], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=datetime], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=datetime-local], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=email], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=month], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=number], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=password], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=range], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=search], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=tel], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=text], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=time], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=url], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=week], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form select, div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form textarea {
    padding: 18px 0px 18px 26px;
}
div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form .wpforms-field-label {
    font-family: 'DIN PRO';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #333333;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
div.wpforms-container div.wpforms-uploader {
    width: 330px;
    height: 193px;
}
div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=checkbox], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=radio] {
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
}
div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=submit], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form button[type=submit], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form .wpforms-page-button {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 10px 330px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    background: #333333;
    color: white;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    pointer-events: none;
        width: 660px;
    height: 55px;
    border-bottom: solid gray 1px; font-family: DIN pro;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image]

Comment: first add extra div and place submit button in div and add ::before in div

Comment: check again @VivekTarsariya i update the question

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared two icon buttons for you. One works with a hover and the other without a hover.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #333333;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 660px;
  border-bottom: solid gray 1px
}


/* Darker background on mouse-over */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #444444;
}

.btn .ic-line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ddd;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  top: 0;
}

.fa-custom {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 22px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn .ic-line1 {
  width: 1px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ddd;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.fa-custom1 {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 22px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover .ic-line1 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.btn:hover .fa-custom1 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<h2>Icon Buttons</h2>
<p>Icon buttons:</p>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-custom"></i><i class="ic-line"></i>Send</button>


<h2>Icon Buttons When hover</h2>
<p>Icon buttons:</p>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-custom1"></i><i class="ic-line1"></i>Send</button>
```